# Edge Chromium giving Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Tags: microsoft-edge, looker-studio

I am trying to embed a Google Data Studio report in an iframe for a static site.
When opening that static site, in Edge Chromium 83.0.478.37 I recieve this error and the data studio report does not appear. It is a clean default install of Edge Chromium, with no settings modified.

```
Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/<urlofreport>.

error:
datastudio__en.js?cb=312620414:3587 ERROR DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

I've found [this information](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document), but in my Edge Chromium, that setting is disabled:
[Disabled block third-party cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPYmy.png).
The thing that seems to work is to add an Exception in the "Privacy and services" tab in Edge Settings for the domain embedding the iframe. This seems unneccessary, especially when the same static site works on newest versions on both Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox. It also seems unnecessary when Data Studio support [suggests](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/9269345?hl=en) to use newest Edge. I don't recieve this error when opening the Data Studio report directly in a tab

Comment: Do you mean after turning off the tracking prevention for the site domain, the error will disappear? If that is the case, perhaps the website contains the potentially harmful trackers, so, the Microsoft Edge tracking prevention will block it. As you said, you could turn off the tacking prevention for that site. More detail information about tracking prevention, please check [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4533959/microsoft-edge-learn-about-tracking-prevention?ocid=EdgePrivacySettings-TrackingPrevention).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Yes, after adding an exception in the tracking prevention settings in the link you've provided, it works. 

Note:
The error seems to origin from the iframe itself - because the datastudio.js file is trying to access localStorage. A [simple example](https://storage.googleapis.com/saga-spikes-df-sf-dev/test.html) that causes the error.

However, the domain or URL I add in the exception is the URL that hosts the example, and it doesn't contain any harmful content. And as I said, this works on a default install for every other major browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the [simple example](https://storage.googleapis.com/saga-spikes-df-sf-dev/test.html) on my side using Microsoft Edge Chromium 83.0.478.37 version. If we use F12 developer tools to check it, we can see in the Console tab, it contains multiple Tracking prevention blocked Warning and the error message.

[image]

After adding the url "https://storage.googleapis.com" in the Edge Tracking Prevention Exception, the warning and the error message will disappear.

[image]

So, the issue might be related to the Google Data Studio or Edge Tracking Prevention, I suggest you could feedback this issue to the [Google Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7340016?hl=en) and Edge browser (click the Send feedback button on the right corner of the Edge browser).

As a workaround, you could add the domain or URL in Edge Tracking Prevention Exception to prevent tracking prevention for that site